# The DOM tree represantation based on css selectors

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm a bit confused with this task that I have: I need to write a dom representation of these selectors:

[image: CSS style selectors]

Currently I have written this html markup:

```html
<div class="red well">
  <div id="loop">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tryied this code but it seems that I have made some kind of logical mistake. Any advise why my html markup does not get the properties from the image above?

Answer (score 2):

The DOM representation should be

```
<div class="red well">
  <div id="loop">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">...</a>
        <!-- 0 or more nodes here -->
        <img src="" alt="" />

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is a following sibling (`~`) - not necessarily an immediate sibling - of the link, not a child.

`~` is the "general sibling selector".

Comment: It makes sense now! Thanks a lot.